# Jquery ui dialog input text as title not working

Tags: jquery-ui, input, dialog

I'm using Jquery Ui to make a dialog using the following options:

```
$("#locations-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: '<input type="text" id="location-name" value="New Location">',
    draggable: false,
    modal: false,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    width: 660,
    height: 515,
});
```

As it is visible I'm using an input field as a title.

The issue I'm having is that  when I click on top of it nothing happens meaning I can't edit the text.

Don't know if I'm doing anything wrong...but in the jquery ui says:

> Any valid HTML may be set as the title

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577012/jquery-ui-dialog-input-textbox-in-the-titlebar-is-disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, that's because the dialog widget disables selection for all the elements in its title bar, even if the `draggable` option is set to `false`.

You can add the text box to the title bar after the dialog widget is created, as the answer to the duplicate question suggests, or you can call `enableSelection()` to re-enable selection on the title bar elements:

```
$("#locations-dialog").dialog("widget")
                      .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar")
                      .find("*").andSelf()
                      .enableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

The binding of the dialog box is what is causing issue. See this URL for full explanation and a work around example.

[jQuery UI Dialog - Input textbox in the titlebar is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577012/jquery-ui-dialog-input-textbox-in-the-titlebar-is-disabled)